# Android SocialAuth retrieves null for some of the profile fields

Tags: android

I have implemented the socialAuth library.But my problem is i cannot retrieve complete profile details.Is there any way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now SocialAuth lib is depreciated.You wont get complete profile details because now social media has improved their security.But you can try it by making profile details as public(goto profile setting and make certain detail public like birth date etc)
Instead of socialAuth try official SDk